# pure css text marquee

Tags: css, marquee

Regarding pure css 'marquee' Im using the following vertical top code on my blogger blog.

```css
#marquee {
width:100%;
height:410px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#marquee p {
display:inline-block;
padding-top:100%;
animation:marquee 100s linear infinite;
}
#marquee p:hover {
animation-play-state: paused
}
@keyframes marquee {
0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
100% { transform: translate(0, -100%); }
}
```

```html
<div id="marquee">
<div class="marquee">
<p>
```

It works as intend it (bottom to top with hidden overflow) but strangely (for me at least) the text color isnt the same as the text color of other posts and pages, which is #0093dd as I set it up.

I spent around 8h searching and experimenting ways to put marquee text of this color. I tried everything (on css template and on html post) but without sucess. :(

Thus,..
Some of stackoverflow experts knows (and can share here please) the trick to put text of this color?

Taking the chance,... the marquee scrolling speed is 100s but stills to fast. It is normal? I guess not comparing with other users of this type of function.

Looking forward for feedbacks about to solve these 2 issues.

Thanks in advance.
Sincerely,

Rubasi

Comment: there is some code missing

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 50px 0; /*remove*/
 border:1px solid red; /*remove*/
 position:relative;
 /*overflow:hidden; */ /*add back */
}
.container .text {
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.4); /*remove*/
  color:#0093dd; /*set color*/
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top:100%;
    transform: translate(0, 0%);
  }
  100% {
    top: 0%;
    transform: translate(0,-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code not work = color didnt changed to #0093dd and scroll stills to fast.
After search for more pure css marquee,..

.marquee {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 410px;
overflow: hidden;
animation: marquee 8s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
0% {top: 10em}
100% {top: -2em}
}

This shows text on color:#0093dd even without being mention on code* and has the right speed scroll.

The problem is this code not shows all text.
After few seconds it stops showing more text and repeat the some text
Maybe use this code but with some changes in away to show all text

Comment: Hey, I really liked the use of nested CSS classes.  It solved a problem with .marquee .span, when the span is embedded in the marquee text.